# Are there a logs to harvest on Oracle Active Data Guard instance?

Tags: oracle-19c, dataguard, data

We are trying to see if there is a way for cloud/SaaS-based( like AirByte or Fivetran) CDC/replicate provider to harvest logs on Oracle active data guard instance.

Any ideas?

Comment: /Which/ Logs do you [think you] want to harvest?  
What /Problem/ are you trying to solve by doing so?

Comment: From an active-standby instance. The way Active Data Guard gets its data from the actual Oracle DB is by replaying log into active-standby instance. What I'm asking is if an active-standby instance has its own logs that can be harvested by another tool.

Comment: Again - why?  
Oracle database Redo is basically only understandable by Oracle databases.  What would you /do/ with this data, even if you could get hold of it?

Comment: There are high-volume connectors that use redo logs to track changes in the oracle database. It is usually done by replaying redo logs but in our case, we want to go after the Oracle Active Data Guards' standby instance. We want to track CDCs from Oracle.